# Ignore http.Server timeout options for `/debug/pprof`

Tags: go, pprof

I am using [net/http/pprof](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof) package to profile the golang app using a `http.Server`, which is configured with timeouts:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := &http.Server{
        Addr:         ":8080",
        ReadTimeout:  time.Second * 5,
        WriteTimeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServe())
}
```

I want to keep timeouts, but I also want to perform long profiling for `/debug/pprof/profile` or `/debug/pprof/trace`. With current settings I get the error:

```sh
$ go tool pprof -http localhost:43242 http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/profile\?seconds\=10

http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/profile?seconds=10: server response: 400 Bad Request - profile duration exceeds server's WriteTimeout
```

I could run a separate `http.Server` on a different port, but I would like to use an existing server

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16100